# Python automate Assign parent relation and keep transform

Tags: python, scripting

I have automated the task of parenting in Blender with Python.
The code affects the relation parent according to the two last characters of the names of the objects.
example:

```
obj1.name = Cube.01
obj2.name = Suzanne.01
```

If `obj1` is in the group "children" and `obj2` is not in the group "children" : `obj2` is the parent of `obj1`.
My code works, but without keeping children's transformation.
How can I do to keep the children's transformation?

```
import bpy

for obj1 in bpy.context.selected_objects:    
    if obj1.name in  bpy.data.groups["Children"].objects:
    a = obj1.name[-2:]

    for obj2 in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            if obj2.name not in  bpy.data.groups["Children"].objects:
                b = obj2.name[-2:]
                if a == b:                       
                   obj1.parent= obj2
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to set the inverse matrix  of the child to clear the initial transformation of the parent at parenting moment :

```
obj1.parent= obj2
obj1.matrix_parent_inverse = obj2.matrix_world.inverted()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for clearing the scale. Any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: this will not keep transform, at least in blender 3.1 when your parent is a curve. if you find the solution could you please post it here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273079/parenting-to-a-curve-with-python-leads-to-unexplained-results

Answer (score 2):

An additional note to [Chebhou](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/5113/chebhou)'s answer and for other community members searching for answers related to keeping the child's transform when the parent object is a [`Curve`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/index.html). The solution comes from [this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273079/parenting-to-a-curve-with-python-leads-to-unexplained-results): If your parent object is a Curve, you need to set the `use_path` property of the curve's data to `False`.

```
curve.data.use_path = False
obj.parent = curve
obj.matrix_parent_inverse = curve.matrix_world.inverted()
```