# parent object to vertex in python - transformation change

Tags: python, animation, vertices, transforms, parent

I've tried parenting object to vertex in python.
However, when I change the object, the object transformed to another location.

I found the related post:

[Python automate Assign parent relation and keep transform](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29122/python-automate-assign-parent-relation-and-keep-transform)

which suggests to do the following:

```
obj1.parent= obj2
obj1.matrix_parent_inverse = obj2.matrix_world.inverted()
```

It works, However, when I change parent type to vertex:

```
obj.parent_type = 'VERTEX'
```

It changes it again to another location.
Someone knows what is the correction to vertex type?

Comment: IMO that is wrong     See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/169424/15543  examples of empty parenting https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200718/vertex-parented-empties-become-offset-after-set-origin-to-3d-cursor/200719#200719   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/202509/assigning-an-empty-parent-object   What is the goal here? do you want the empty at vertex location?

Comment: @batFINGER The purpose is human face expressions, I have eyelashes and I want to make non rigid expression, so I want that each eyelashes will be a child of the its own nearest vertex (so when the face makes an expression, so it move non rigidly).
Some of the links looks relevant, I'll try to figure it out.